# Django project page cannot shown on ubuntu after uninstalling pycharm

Tags: 20.04, pycharm

Recently I bought a 2handed laptop and try to develop django project
I have removed Pycharm-professional that was installed from snap, then I cannot view django project's pages
it shows the error below:

```
TypeError at /en/cms_wizard/create/
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/cms_wizard/create/
Django Version: 3.1.14
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Exception Location: /home/userm/PycharmProjects/tehranradar/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cms/wizards/views.py, line 157, in get_selected_entry
Python Executable:  /home/userm/PycharmProjects/tehranradar/env/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.10.6
Python Path:    
['/home/userm/PycharmProjects/tehranradar/thecms',
 '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/home/userm/PycharmProjects/tehranradar/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 15 Jul 2023 19:41:31 +0330


META
    Variable    Value
    APPCODE_VM_OPTIONS  
    '/home/userm/Downloads/Files/JetBrains.PyCharm.Professional.v2022.2.x64.Crack.Only_pd/Crack/ja-netfilter-all/vmoptions/appcode.vmoptions'
    CLION_VM_OPTIONS    
    '/home/userm/Downloads/Files/JetBrains.PyCharm.Professional.v2022.2.x64.Crack.Only_pd/Crack/ja-netfilter-all/vmoptions/clion.vmoptions'
    COLORTERM   
    'truecolor'
    CONTENT_LENGTH  
    '1014'
    CONTENT_TYPE    
    'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryG174ZOv4Rbg7rsje'
    CSRF_COOKIE 
    'Xj6uHjxyIE6v6Lfbmq7PZDl07XgkxtNaAls73sHfqcIdRS4CYiUl3nbM3pP6mPiX'
    DATAGRIP_VM_OPTIONS 
    '/home/userm/Downloads/Files/JetBrains.PyCharm.Professional.v2022.2.x64.Crack.Only_pd/Crack/ja-netfilter-all/vmoptions/datagrip.vmoptions'
    DATASPELL_VM_OPTIONS    
    '/home/userm/Downloads/Files/JetBrains.PyCharm.Professional.v2022.2.x64.Crack.Only_pd/Crack/ja-netfilter-all/vmoptions/dataspell.vmoptions'
    DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS    
    'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
    DEFAULTS_PATH   
    '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path'
    DESKTOP_SESSION 
    'ubuntu'
    DEVECOSTUDIO_VM_OPTIONS 
    '/home/userm/Downloads/Files/JetBrains.PyCharm.Professional.v2022.2.x64.Crack.Only_pd/Crack/ja-netfilter-all/vmoptions/devecostudio.vmoptions'
    DISPLAY 
    ':1'
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  
    'thecms.settings'
    GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
    'CGI/1.1'
    GATEWAY_VM_OPTIONS  
    '/home/userm/Downloads/Files/JetBrains.PyCharm.Professional.v2022.2.x64.Crack.Only_pd/Crack/ja-netfilter-all/vmoptions/gateway.vmoptions'
    GDMSESSION  
    'ubuntu'
    GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE   
    '/usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop'
```